# Asp Net Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:0A000152:SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, ubuntu

I a getting an SSL Handshake error on an Ubuntu server in ASP.Net Core

I am getting the following error from an HttpClient request.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
       ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
       ---> Interop+OpenSsl+SslException: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.
       ---> Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:0A000152:SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled
```

I simulated the request in curl and got a similar error.

Answer (score 0):

I was connecting to bluesnap and the error code meant that the endpoint does not allow TLS renegotiation starting below TLS 1.3.

Now, these curl requests worked on Windows, but not Linux. And only for a specific endpoint. It appeared that Windows negotiated TLS version from 1.3 downward while Linux negotiated upwards from 1.0.

In my case I needed to specify TLS 1.3. I did not want to do it globally so I did it like so with my HttpClient:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls13 };
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.RequestUri = new Uri(url);
```

Check your endpoint and see if it requires a specific version of TLS.